# I have problem in connect flutter in firebase

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase

Hi I have this problem:

> C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flare_flutter-3.0.2/lib/flare_render_box.dart:272:26:
> Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.

- 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart'
  ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
  SchedulerBinding.instance?.cancelFrameCallbackWithId(_frameCallbackID);

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From your error: "type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null" - try just replace "?." to "."